# Do epsilon transitions in an nfa accept any input?

Tags: state-machine, automata, nfa, epsilon

If i have this transition in my nfa

```
            epsilon
( q1 ) ----------------> ( q2 )
```

for the alphabet {a,b}

does that mean that there is a transtion from q1 to q2 when either b or a is read as input when the nfa is in state q1? Or are there no transitions defined from q1 to q2 on inputs a and b

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They don't consume any input. That is anytime you are in state `q1` you can jump to state `q2` no matter the input.